# ProgrammingError while opening admin table

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-admin

I am using django with postgres database.
When loading the admin,clicking on Course Table, I get a classic error:

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/user_profile/course/
relation "user_profile_course" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "user_profile_course"
```

I tried makemigrations, and migrate it again but no success.

Would you please help me how to handle it?

My models.py looks like:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    number_of_sessions=models.IntegerField()
    student=models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Registration')
```

Edit:

I removed the migration folder, and make migrations again.
in the 0001initial.py the dependencies looks like:

```
dependencies = [
    ('auth', '0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages'),
]
```

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at your custom admin urls and custom admin views.

Comment: Are your migrations fine?

Comment: @allcaps I have access to other tables with similar urls and views.

Comment: @sprksh I guess the problem is with migrations but I do not know how should I change them and what is the problem with them.

Comment: when you run python manage.py makemigrations and then python manage.py migrate, do you see errors? if yes please post that.

Comment: @sprksh no, I edited my question. should I clear these dependencies?

Comment: perhaps you landed in some bigger trouble by deleting the migration folder. And when you are a beginner, don't mess with migration folder or the content of migration files directly.

Comment: @sprksh I didn't know that. I guess I can recover it from github. What do you recommend me?

Comment: what does python manage.py migrate say? How big is the project? how many tables? how many rows in django_migrations table?

Comment: @sprksh 
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: corrector, simple_email_confirmation, auth, contenttypes, user_profile, admin, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

Comment: can't suggest any real solution without all data. Try running python manage.py makemigrations, if that is fine and migration is created, migrate it. else if there is an error, try restoring the files from git. Else if makemigrations does not gives any error and no migrationsare made try the same sequence after adding a field to any of the models. 
If you have deleted the entire migration folder along with __init__.py, try restoring from git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've removed already applied migration from your migrations folder and re-created it with different model state (with extra model `Course`).

That will create situation when actual structure of your database is different than state that should be after applying your migration.

Now you can either fix your migration or fix your database structure.

To accomplish first possible fix, you need to check your current state of database and compare it with your migration file. If there is something different in your migration file, simply change it to reflect your database structure.

If you don't know how to edit migration file, you can change your models to reflect database structure, remove your migration and then create it again using `makemigrations`.

After fixing your migration file, generate second one, just running `makemigrations` with having desired models structure in your models files.

For second solution, check what's inside your migration file and edit your database structure to reflect that.

And remember, do not ever delete or change already applied migration, unless you really know what you're doing!

Comment: Would you please tell me how to change migrations exactly? I face ValueError because when I cleared a model, there was a foreign key in another model maintained.